# How to pass implicit vals defined through package objects from Scala in Java

Tags: java, scala, implicit, scala-cats, scala-java-interop

I am using the Cats library. In Scala the code looks like:

```
import cats.Semigroupal
import cats.instances.option._
val r = Semigroupal.tuple2(Option(1), Option(2))
```

The `tuple2` defined as:

```
def tuple2[F[_], A0, A1](f0:F[A0], f1:F[A1])(implicit semigroupal: Semigroupal[F], invariant: Invariant[F]):F[(A0, A1)]
```

The following implicit value is actually passed both as `Semigroupal` and as  `Invariant` (checked via Intellij IDEA plugin for Scala):

```
package cats
package instances

trait OptionInstances ...
  implicit val catsStdInstancesForOption: ...
```

How to pass `catsStdInstancesForOption` in `tuple2` function from Java code?

```
Semigroupal$.MODULE$.tuple2(
  Option.apply(1), Option.apply(2),
  ...,// and here?
  ... //here 
  );
```

Dependency on the Cats library, if needed:

```
<cats.core.version>1.5.0</cats.core.version>
...
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.typelevel</groupId>
  <artifactId>cats-core_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${cats.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide a Java-friendlier wrapper method (possibly specialized for the types you are going to need) written in Scala and call into that instead.

Comment: @Thilo, I can. But I want to know, why I cannot use catsStdInstancesForOption in Java. I have hundred of methods with implicit values in the cats, it is not effective to write wrappers for all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to Scala objects defined inside package objects from Java is a pain, and as far as I can tell there's no good reason for this—it's entirely because of the way the compiler decides to mangle names (e.g. you can't refer directly to `cats.instances.package$option$` from Java).

I've wanted to do this kind of thing before, and the best solution I've found is something like this:

```
import cats.Apply;
import cats.Semigroupal$;
import cats.instances.OptionInstances;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import scala.Option;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class Test {
  public static Apply<Option> getOptionInstance() {
    try {
      Class<?> cls = Class.forName("cats.instances.package$option$");
      Field f = cls.getField("MODULE$");
      Method m = f.getType().getMethod("catsStdInstancesForOption");
      return (Apply<Option>) m.invoke(f.get(null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Shouldn't happen but do something here anyway.
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apply<Option> optionInstance = getOptionInstance();

    Option<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> pair = Semigroupal$.MODULE$.tuple2(
      Option.apply(1),
      Option.apply(2),
      optionInstance,
      optionInstance
    );

    System.out.println(pair);
  }
}
```

It's terrible, but at least the reflection and casting are bundled up in one place.

If you have lots of instances you need to use from Java, you could abstract some of the logic out of `getOptionInstance` to cut down on repetition, but it's still not going to be fun. If you can write some utility code on the Scala side to use from Java, it wouldn't be too hard to make a more Java-friendly `cats.instances`—just don't use package objects, etc. (For what it's worth I wish Cats had kept more of an eye on Java-friendliness during its development, but as far as I can tell nobody else cared about that at all.)

Comment: great answer. Thank you very much. Unfortunately the whole solution is ugly, but nevertheless it works! It seems a library for Scala should also provide some helper methods to be able to use the library classes from Java code.